# Does a bijection from the natural numbers to the integer numbers exist?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I don't consider myself advanced in the huge field of mathematics (yet), but I do find my current acquirements commendable in the very least. The question I'm about to ask may appear foolish to those more proffesional, but I inquire out of true thirst.

Sometimes, I'd hear a mathematician speak of a bijection from one set to another; specifically, I'd hear him speak of a bijection from the set of natural numbers to the set of integer numbers. I do plan on studying bijections thoroughly, yet this problem can't leave my mind. How does such a bijection exist? I do, in fact, know that the set of integer numbers contains the set of natural numbers; hence I deem it impossible to construct such a function. For it must be the case that the function is both onto and injective.

For the bijection to exist, the set must map all natural numbers to the integers; and there are more integers than the natural numbers. So not all integers will be paired. Also, vice versa: I don't see how a bijection from the integers to the natural numbers exist; for no injection can be made.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you can make a list of them then you have a bijection with the naturals. Can you list the integers?

Comment: You've discovered [Galileo's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_paradox).  The natural numbers are a proper subset of the integers, but there is a still a bijection.  (Galileo's example was that the perfect squares $1,4,9,16,25\ldots$ are a proper subset of the natural numbers, but there is an obvious bijection.)

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&\cdots\\0&1&-1&2&-2&3&-3&4&-4&\cdots\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Incidentally, this seemingly paradoxical property, that the whole set can be placed in bijection with a proper subset, is so characteristic of the infinite that [it is sometimes used as a definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind-infinite_set).

Comment: @Stinking Bishop: I find it interesting that this question could even occur in modern times (say, after 1900), since I would be surprised that anyone would even have heard about the possibility without also having it demonstrated. In my case, I saw it in various "recreational type" math public/school library books in the early 1970s (age around 12-14, in a somewhat rural area) -- Gamow's "One, Two, Three ... Infinity", probably more than once in an Isaac Asimov F&SF essay, probably at least once in something by Martin Gardiner, in Lillian R. Lieber's **(continued)**

Comment: "Infinity. Beyond the Beyond the Beyond", in Zippin's "Uses of Infinity", in Edna E. Kramer's "The Nature and Growth of Modern Mathematics", etc. In fact, it's even in [my high school algebra 2 text](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0054H9MW6) (*Extra for Experts* on pp. 349-351 discusses one-to-one correspondence of natural numbers with the integers, with the rationals, and not with the real numbers via the standard diagonalization method). My point is that this is not something I would expect someone to have encountered without actually seeing how it can be done.